# In PHP which operator should i use '<' or '<='?

Tags: php

I am using the following code :

```
<?php
$start_time = microtime(true);
for($i=1;$i <= 999999; $i++){

}
$end_time = microtime(true);
echo "Time Interval : ".$end_time-$start_time;

$start_time = microtime(true);
for($j=1;$j < 1000000; $j++){

}
$end_time = microtime(true);
echo "Time Interval : ".$end_time-$start_time;
?>
```

It shows met the time difference between them of 0.0943 seconds.So in this way <= operator is faster than '<'. I just wanna know if there is any disadvantage of using <= operator over '<'?

Comment: just checking, you do realise they are different comparisons : "Less than" and "less than or equal"

Comment: This is the worst form of premature optimization I've seen in ages.

Comment: I have tried your code out of curiosity and < works consistently faster than <=, even though as other people said here it doesn't matter at all. If you want to optimize your script, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: I had never give any weight-age to this while developing. It just came to my mind and just asked. I think to know about anything is not worst it will just improve your knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is certainly no performance penalty. Both operands are single opcode in PHP bytecode, and ultimately both should be executed using exactly one CPU instruction.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.is-smaller.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.is-smaller-or-equal.php

and of course I agree with comments - you should never optimize things at this low level of your code.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

> "Premature optimization" is a phrase used to describe a situation
>   where a programmer lets performance considerations affect the design
>   of a piece of code. This can result in a design that is not as clean
>   as it could have been or code that is incorrect, because the code is
>   complicated by the optimization and the programmer is distracted by
>   optimizing.

Usually I'd stick with having meaningful code vs. faster code that's less meaningful. That guard will probably be a value coming from a variable defined elsewhere, so you should keep it's meaning. You shouldn't change all your `<` to `<=` to save a fraction of time (which may be a random error).